# Extract a block of XML into another XML file in java

Tags: java, xml, file-io, xml-parsing

I have a XML file called word.xml containing

```
<A> 
<Answer>How was you day</Answer> 
<Question>Happy day </Question>
<Biased> good morning </Biased>
<abc>..............</abc>
.
. // few more tags here
.
</A>
```

Now i want to extract another XML file called word1.xml containing part of word1.xml

```
<A> 
<Answer>How was you day</Answer> 
<Question>Happy day </Question>
</A>
```

Java Code which I tried so far

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class ReadXMLFile {

public static void main(String args[]) {
try {

File stocks = new File("word.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(stocks);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

System.out.println("root of xml file" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("A");
System.out.println("==========================");

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
Node node = nodes.item(i);
System.out.println("i value---"+i);
System.out.println(nodes.getLength());
if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
Element element = (Element) node;
System.out.println(element.getTextContent());
//element.getElementsByTagName(name)
File statText = new File(i+".txt");
FileOutputStream is = new FileOutputStream(statText);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(is);    
Writer w = new BufferedWriter(osw);
w.write("<Answer>");
w.write(element.getElementsByTagName("Answer").item(0).getTextContent());
w.write("</Answer>");
w.write("Question");
w.write(element.getElementsByTagName("Question").item(0).getTextContent());
w.write("</Question>");
w.close();
}
}
}
catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}

private static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
NodeList nodes = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
Node node = (Node) nodes.item(0);
return node.getNodeValue();
}
}
}
```

I just want to include tags in my results. This is the DIRTY way of doing. Can you please suggest me the best way.Need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Explain what you mean by `extract another XML file`. Do you just want to put the contents into a string? Are you wanting to combine the two files into one file or string? What is your objective? Also, please post the  Java code you have tried so far. Thanks.

Comment: the </id> bit is invalid, did you mean <id/> ?

Comment: Please clean up your code sample. It's generally accepted that `imports` or in the case of Java, the class or method definition surrounding your code or checked exception handling isn't really necessary - most people are fine with something that can be copy/pasted into a `main()` method and touched up by an IDE as long as the code is correct otherwise. Also, indenting.

Comment: Also, if I understand your examples correctly: what you're doing is removing all children of `<A>` except `<Question>` and `<Answer>`, right?

Comment: Yes you are right @millimoose

Comment: @user2765031 Well, then the straightforward approach is to remove those tags from the `Document` object, then write out the modified document. (This sort of thing is kind of what DOM is for.) See: http://ideone.com/rY8gGt Aside: The standard Java DOM is completely awful. Do yourself a favour and use JDOM instead. You don't have to reimplement DOM output but it's hidden two locations, both somewhat obscure. (The usual `Transformer` trick, and using `DOMImplementationLS`.)

Answer (score 2):

If Java is not a mandatory constraint here, you can achieve this by using XSLT. It's pretty easy to follow. You can find some guidance here: [Link](http://oreilly.com/catalog/orxmlapp/chapter/ch07.pdf)

An example of my own practice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//title">
        <article>
            <title> 
                <xsl:value-of select="./name/>
                <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select = "./number/>
            </title>
            <references>
                <xsl:value-of select = "reference"/>
            </references>
        </article>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just like BeginnerJava explained XSL is the most appropriate technology here as you are transforming one XML tree to another XML tree and XSL is meant for that.
in XSL the code needed to achieve what you describe would be (I skipped some bits):

```
<xsl:template match="A">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Answer|Question"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You can invoke XSL transfomation from you Java code or from command line like this:

```
java  net.sf.saxon.Transform   [options]   source-document   stylesheet   [ params…]
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the xml into DOM using a DocumentParser.  remove the elements that you don't need from the resulting Document.  write the modified Document to a new File using a Transformer.  (note, the details for each of these steps can be found in any of the thousands of java xml tutorials online).

Comment: -1: This isn't even a link-only answer which would be bad enough. You're basically saying "Google for some random words from the previous sentence."

Comment: @millimoose - the OP doesn't know where to start, so i gave the highlights.  i could cut-n-paste a bunch of code from online tutorials, but what's the point there?  reading the online tutorials would be better for the OP than me writing the code for them.

Comment: @millimoose - obviously this answer was useful to the OP as the example code posted later clearly follows what i wrote.

Comment: That's an assumption you have no proof of, and useful hints still belong into comments, not answers which should ideally have actual content.

Comment: @millimoose - so why don't you write up an answer?

Comment: Because the question is closed and you can't add answers anymore until it's reopened. (Which I voted for, seems appropriate after the OP's edit.) I gave the OP a comment linking to an "answer" (commented code) on ideone.com. Two hours ago. HTH HAND

Comment: @millimoose - oh, missed the link.  nice code.  i see that you followed my answer as well.